# Repeat example in LaTeX, but with double numbering (incremental and old)

Tags: numbering, linguistics, examples, gb4e

I am using gb4e to write my thesis and I need to repeat examples by presenting them using both the new number (example 4 follows example 3) and the original number they were presented first with. For instance, example (1) is presented again as a fourth example.

Something like:

(1) This is an example.

(2) This is a second example.

(3) This is a third example.

(4) = (1) This is an (repeated) example.

I know of \exr, but I really need to have the double numbering on the repeated example.

This is the code I am using right now, but I do not know how to include the "=" sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
        \ex {This is an example.} \label{exe:original-example}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
        \ex {This is a second example.} %\label{exe:original-example}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
        \ex {This is a third example.} %\label{exe:original-example}
\end{exe}

Example \ref{exe:repeated-example} repeats example \ref{exe:original-example}

\begin{exe}
        \ex \label{exe:repeated-example} \begin{xlist}
            \exr{exe:original-example}[]{This is an (repeated) example.} 
            \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

And it gives the output in picture:[image]

If I try to add an equal sign between the two numbers, LateX moves the second number and the text of the example on the following row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
        \ex {This is an example.} \label{exe:original-example}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
        \ex {This is a second example.} %\label{exe:original-example}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
        \ex {This is a third example.} %\label{exe:original-example}
\end{exe}

Example \ref{exe:repeated-example} repeats example \ref{exe:original-example}

\begin{exe}
        \ex \label{exe:repeated-example} = \begin{xlist}
            \exr{exe:original-example}[]{This is an (repeated) example.} 
            \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any ideas how I could do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this. It has the following restrictions:

1. It only works for top-level (`{exe}`) examples, not `xlist` examples.  The repeated example number itself can be a reference to any level of example however.
2. Each repeated example must be in its own environment.

### Usage

```
\begin{rex}{<label-of-previous-example>}
\ex Example as usual
\label{<label-of-current-example>}
\end{rex}
```

### Sample document

In this sample, I've deliberately increased the example number in the last examples to show that the spacing of the new numbers is preserved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\makeatletter
\def\@exr[#1]{\ifnum \@xnumdepth >0%
                 \if@xrec\@exrecwarn\fi%
                 \if@noftnote\@exrecwarn\fi%
                 \@xnumdepth0\@listdepth0\@xrectrue%
                 \save@counters%
              \fi%
                 \advance\@xnumdepth \@ne \@@xsi%
                 \exewidth{(234)=(\ref{\tmplabel})}
                 \begin{list}{(\thexnumi)=(\ref{\tmplabel})}%
                             {\usecounter{xnumi}\@subex{#1}{1em}%
                              \if@noftnote%
                                 \setcounter{xnumi}{\value{exx}}%
                              \else%
                                 \setcounter{xnumi}{\value{fnx}}%
                      \fi}}

\def\rex#1{\def\tmplabel{#1}\@ifnextchar [{\@exr}{\@exr[\@exwidth]}}
\let\endrex\endexe
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex This is the original example.
\label{exe:orginal-example}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex This is a second example.
\label{exe:second-example}
\end{exe}
\begin{rex}{exe:orginal-example}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex This is a sub-example \label{subex:another-label}
\ex This is another one
\end{xlist}
\end{rex}
\begin{rex}{subex:another-label}
\ex[*]{This is a second example}
\end{rex}
\setcounter{exx}{10}
\begin{exe}
\ex A bigger example number. \label{exe:bigger}
\end{exe}
\begin{rex}{exe:bigger}
\ex A repeated bigger example
\end{rex}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]